# How to adjust the baseline length

Tags: java, android, xml, material-components

How to adjust the length of the baseline of a `TextInputEditText` to match exactly this example:

[image]

My `TextInputEditText` now looks like:

[image]

my intention is that the line below the text is aligned with the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `android:minLines` to 2 and set the `gravity` to bottom.

Also you might need to designate the height to a certain value as `android:minLines` increases the height according to the number of lines. Here I set it to `50dp`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Escreva seu feedback">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp" 
        android:minLines="2" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Result:

[image]